# Can gdb used to step through the assembler instructions of a program not compiled with -g?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, breakpoints

I tried to run a program which is not compiled with the -g option inside `gdb` in Linux (e.g. /bin/ls). `gdb` runs the program (BTW `lldb` does not). I wonder whether it is possible to execute the program stepping through the machine instructions with `si`(I don't see why not, in principle). But the question is: how do you set breakpoints? If you simply run the program, it executes and exits.

Comment: You set breakpoints using addresses of course. You can also use `starti` to have the program stop at the first instruction and single step from there.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course:

- Use `starti` to start the program but break on the first instruction
- Use `disassemble` to show the instructions for the current function
- Use `break *0x00007ffff7ec3f2d` to set a breakpoint by address

Comment: You can even use `layout reg` (or `layout next` / `prev`) to get a pane for disassembly and another pane for register values that highlights the one(s) that changed since the last prompt.  See also the GDB asm tips at the bottom of [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), although it actually applies to asm for any ISA.